# How to call the SOAP Request/Response in another Class in Swift Code?

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, soap

This is the situation. I am using XCode 6.4 and Yosemite.

I've got two classes: "ViewController" and a new class "WebService". 
I need to start WebService class, in ViewController.

WebService is this code: [Code Here](http://webindream.com/soap-with-swift/)

And I need to pass a string parameter, from ViewController when I call WebService class.

Can you help me? I'm a newbie with Swift on iOS.

P.S: sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally works.
In this example, I use a button click event for Web Service call.

CallWebService.swift (without XML parsing) :

```
class CallWebService: UIViewController
{

func BuildMessage1(Rupp: String)-> String
{
    var is_SoapMessage = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><HelloAppleAndroid xmlns='http://testestest.org/'><RUPP>\(Rupp)</RUPP></HelloAppleAndroid></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

    return is_SoapMessage
}


func HelloWebService(Rupp: String)
{
    var is_SoapMessage = BuildMessage1(Rupp)

    var is_URL: String = "http://testesttest/webservice.asmx"

    var lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: is_URL)!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var err: NSError?

    lobj_Request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    lobj_Request.HTTPBody = is_SoapMessage.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    lobj_Request.addValue("testest.it", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    lobj_Request.addValue(String(count(is_SoapMessage)), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    lobj_Request.addValue("http://testest.org/HelloAppleAndroid", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(lobj_Request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Body: \(strData)")




        if error != nil
        {
            println("Error: " + error.description)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

}

In ViewController.swift:

```
@IBAction func btnClicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    var getRupp = "ARGTEST093467555"
    CallWebService().HelloWebService(getRupp)
}
```